# Probability of a 50% drop in value recovering to break even in a specified time frame.

Tags: probability

A \$100 contract drops in value to \$50. A 50% decline. It will take a 100% increase in value to break even, ie. return the value to $100. The contract period is 21 days and the decline in value occurred on the 10th day of the contract period.
It seems to me without introducing the time element the probability would be 1 in 50, where 1 equals the only outcome-break even, and 50 equals each one of the 50 percentage points needed to return to original value. I can only get that far. I don’t know how to introduce the time element. Thanks.Leroy

Comment: You are making a great many unstated assumptions, some of them quite unlikely, when you do your calculation. Some assumptions are necessary to make any progress, but they should all be stated clearly and explicitly.

Comment: Help me out. What do you need to make the calculation? What assumptions did I make but not state? Thanks!

Comment: As well, I don’t think the 1/50 is correct after pondering it. So  idk! I  stated everything I know!

Comment: You are assuming that the only possible outcomes are a one point increase, a two point increase, ..., and a $50$ point increase. You are assuming that these $50$ outcomes are equally likely. I see no justification for either one of these assumptions.

Comment: You need to know something about the distribution in change in value per day and whether they are independent to make any calculation of this.  You could look at historical data and ask how often it doubled in value in $10$ days.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.